# Datatype Person mother from mother (grandmother)

Tags: haskell, types, option-type

Imagine I've got a datatype `Person`.

```
data Person = Person String Person
```

The 2. Person should be the mother.

```
showGrandmother :: Person -> Maybe Person
showGrandmother (Person _ mother) = Just mother
```

Will only show the mother from person x.
How can I show the grandmother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, your data definition is missing the base case.  Assuming this represents [matrilineality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrilineality), I would start with `Eve` as the base case

```
data Person = Eve | Person String Person deriving (Show)
```

defining `mother` function

```
mother Eve = Nothing
mother (Person _ m) = Just m
```

now grandmother is applying this twice

```
grandmother = \x -> mother x >>= mother
```

With Control.Monad Kleiski operators, this can be written much nicely

```
grandmother = mother >=> mother
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand that code.
how do i need to modify my function (showGrandmother) that it works?

Comment: @R.Mayer Please try to convert "I don't understand that code" into a question that can be answered. (What is difficult for you to understand? Where are you getting stuck in reading the code?) As for "how do I need to modify my function", well, let's just say the answer to that will follow *incredibly* quickly on understanding the answer written here.

Comment: additional note for naming convention.  your method is not a `show` method.  The return value is not `String` representation but the actual `Person` value, so naming it as `showX` is misleading...

Answer (score 2):

With pattern matching, you aren't limited to one level of constructors, you can nest them to go further "in":

```
showGrandmother :: Person -> Maybe Person
showGrandmother (Person _ (Person _ grandmother)) = Just grandmother
```

---

As a sidenote, I'm not a Haskell expert, but it seems like the data type is a bit circular for what is meant to be a model of a family tree. You can't actually create a person without it referencing another person. Maybe something better would be...

```
data Person = Person String (Maybe Person)
```

... in which case, finding the grandmother can be done as...

```
showGrandmother :: Person -> Maybe Person
showGrandmother (Person _ Just (Person _ (Just grandmother)))) = Just grandmother
showGrandmother _                                              = Nothing
```

... making sure to handle the base case when someone doesn't have a grandmother. Your original type didn't need to handle this case because everyone must have a grandmother according to it.

---

And taking inspiration from the [@Karafka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167758/1319998), it's possible to factor out finding the mother of a person...

```
showMother :: Person -> Maybe Person
showMother (Person _ (Just mother)) = Just mother
showMother _                        = Nothing
```

... and using the fact that `Maybe` is a monad, can use it as below.

```
showGrandmother :: Person -> Maybe Person
showGrandmother x = showMother x >>= showMother
```

I suspect understanding the above monadic code would be out of scope for this particular question.